# random number generator function returns a nested tuple in haskell

Tags: haskell, random, functional-programming

I am trying to understand why my haskell function returns a nested tuple, and I cannot seem to wrap my head around the problem.

I have this function that generates a random binary Int

```
test :: StdGen -> (Int, StdGen)
test g = do
  let (i, g') = randomR (0, 1) g
  return (i, g')
```

However, I cannot compile this unless I change the function to return a nested tuple, like so:

```
test :: StdGen -> (Int, (Int, StdGen))
```

If I do so, I have to get the snd element in the returned tuple, to get the desired result:

```
g = mkStdGen 5
(i, g') = snd test g
```

How do I make my test function return a single tuple with the random binary and a new generator (i, g)? What am I missing?

Comment: remove the `do`. Use `test = randomR (0, 1)`.

Comment: `do` and `return` are for monads: what monad do you want to use here? I guess none, so don't use `do`/`return`. You could write `test g = let (i, g') = randomR (0, 1) g in (i, g')`, but that can even be simplified to `test g = randomR (0, 1) g`, or even to `test = randomR (0, 1)`.

Comment: As already mentioned, the do/return thing is worse than useless. But what range of random integer values do you want ? As is, it seems you want either 0 or 1 and nothing else. Or do you want the full range of the `Int` data type ?

Comment: Your original function doesn't *have* to yield a `(Int, (Int, StdGen))`. It would also work with `[(Int, StdGen)]` or `IO (Int, StdGen)` or many others. It just must return some Monad applied to the pair type `(Int, StdGen)` because, as others have explained, you've erroneously used `do` and `return`

Comment: BTW this _should **not**_ compile with the `(Int, (Int, StdGen))` signature, because tuples form a monad only if the first element is a monoid, which `Int` is not. (Integers do have not only one but two monoid structures, addition and multiplication, but the libraries implement neither of them directly.)

Answer (score 1):

Unlike other languages, where `return` is a keyword that means to immediately exit a procedure and hand off a value to the caller, in Haskell `return` is just another function, and it can do fairly arbitrary things. In Haskell, the way to choose what value to hand off to the caller is to simply state it as *the* value on the right-hand side of an equals sign. So, deleting `return` makes your code work:

```
test :: StdGen -> (Int, StdGen)
test g = do
  let (i, g') = randomR (0, 1) g
  (i, g')
```

However, this way of spelling `test` is a little misleading. Most Haskell programmers use `do` only when they are working with the monadic operators (named `return`, coincidentally, and `(>>=)`) and want a better syntax for them. You are not doing that here; the fact that this code desugars to something sensible would probably surprise some readers. Instead, I recommend explicitly using the code that it desugars to, which isn't even longer:

```
test g =
  let (i, g') = randomR (0, 1) g
  in (i, g')
```

Additionally, this `let X = ... in X` is probably better just written with the content of the definition of `X`:

```
test g = randomR (0, 1) g
```

As a matter of aesthetics, some people will eta reduce this (and some won't -- I am a lot less attached to this suggested change than the previous ones):

```
test = randomR (0, 1)
```